# How to start the cloudwatch agent in container?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

From the docker hub there is an [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/cloudwatch-agent) which is maintained by amazon.

Any one know **how to configure and start the container** as I cannot find any documentation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got this working! I was having the same issue with you when you see `Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/default_linux_config.json ... Cannot access /etc/cwagentconfig: lstat /etc/cwagentconfig: no such file or directoryValid Json input schema.`

What you need to do is put your config file in /etc/cwagentconfig. A functioning dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/cloudwatch-agent:1.230621.0
COPY config.json /etc/cwagentconfig
```

Where config.json is some cloudwatch agent configuration, such as given by LinPy's answer.

You can ignore the warning about `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/default_linux_config.json`, or you can also COPY the config.json file to that location in the dockerfile as well.

I will also share how I found this answer:

I needed this run in ECS as a sidecar, and I could only find docs on how to run it in kubernetes. Following this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-StatsD.html I decided to download all the example k8s manifests, when I saw this one:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: amazonlinux
spec:
  containers:
    - name: amazonlinux
      image: amazonlinux
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
      args: ["-c", "sleep 300"]
    - name: cloudwatch-agent
      image: amazon/cloudwatch-agent
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu:  200m
          memory: 100Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 200m
          memory: 100Mi
      volumeMounts:
        - name: cwagentconfig
          mountPath: /etc/cwagentconfig
  volumes:
    - name: cwagentconfig
      configMap:
        name: cwagentstatsdconfig
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

So I saw that the volume mount `cwagentconfig` mounts to `/etc/cwagentconfig` and that's from the `cwagentstatsdconfig` configmap, and *that's* just the json file.

Comment: Do you have any luck in running the CW agent in the sidecar container?

Answer (score 1):

You just to run the container with `log-opt`, as the log agent is the main process of the container.

```
docker run --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-west-2 --log-opt awslogs-group=myLogGroup amazon/cloudwatch-agent
```

You can find more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/).

I do not know why you need an agent in a container, but the best practice is to send each container log directly to [cloud watch using aws log driver.](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/)

Btw this is entrypoint of the container.

```
  "Entrypoint": [
         "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
 ],
```

All you need to call

```
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent
```

Comment: Thanks once again, but the example you have given is to run any container using awslogs driver which i do not need, and I need an cloudwatch agent due to business requirements :(

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62047222/291754) is how I got it working in our Docker containers without `systemctl` or System V init.

Answer (score -2):

This is from official Documentation:

```
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:configuration-file-path -s
```

here the Docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html#start-CloudWatch-Agent-EC2-commands-fleet

Installation path may be different, but that is how the agent is started as per docs.